# Flatten a binary tree to list (ordered)

Tags: binary

I am trying to implement an algorithm that takes a tree as input and returns a list with all of the values in the correct order (top to bottom, each row left to right) but I am having trouble with it. The easy way to do it unordered is to reduce the entire list where each node gets appended to the accumulated list.

This is the code I wrote to reduce a tree (written in elixir) where each node has a left and right branch which can be another node or nil:

```
    def reduce(nil, op, init), do: init
    def reduce({:node, n, left, right}, op, init) do
      reduce(right, op, reduce(left, op, op.(n, init)))
    end
```

called like this to get the tree (but in the wrong order):

```
    result = reduce(tree, fn (node, acc) -> [acc|node] end, [])
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you could just call `&Enum.reverse/1` on the resulting list. A lot of algorithms you will find do this under the hood due to the nature of the way lists are constructed in erlang. I think even `&Enum.map/2` uses it.

That aside, there's a much easier way to write your functionality with function heads. I believe that you're looking for an inorder traversal of the tree in which each visited node is added to the list, but you could easily modify this to include postorder and preorder traversal as well. Here's a module with the map/reduce functions you're looking for.

```
defmodule Tree do
  # This just uses the reduce functions defined below to create a map.
  def map_inorder(root) do
    root
    |> reduce_inorder([], fn val, acc ->
      [val | acc]
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse()
  end

  # This is the core functionality of the function for an inorder traversal
  # It processes the left subtree then calls the reducer on the root node
  # and then processes the right subtree.
  def reduce_inorder({:node, val, left, right}, acc, fun) do
    left_subtree = reduce_inorder(left, acc, fun)
    visit_root = fun.(val, left_subtree)
    reduce_inorder(right, visit_root, fun)
  end

  # Nil means that you've reached a leaf. There's nothing else to process
  def reduce_inorder(nil, acc, _fun) do
    acc
  end

  # Node does not match the spec you have for the record. Return an error
  def reduce_inorder(_other, _, _) do
    :malformed_node
  end
end
```

Binary tree traversal algorithms are very easy to understand. Here's a post that explains them well.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Cheers!

**EDIT**

I realized that you were talking about breadth first search (BFS) which is an entirely different algorithm. Basically, you have to push the nodes into a queue instead of a stack which is what preorder/postorder/inorder traversal algorithms do.

BFS ensures that all nodes are processed in left to right order within the same depth of the tree. Generally, you start with the root node as the only node in the queue. You process that node and then push its left and right children into the queue in that order and then repeat over the new queue. Luckily, I remembered that erlang has a `:queue` module which makes this much easier. You can find the code below:

```
defmodule Tree do
  def map_tree(root) do
    root
    |> reduce_tree([], fn val, acc ->
      [val | acc]
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse()
  end

  def reduce_tree(root, acc, reducer) do
    :queue.new()
    |> queue_in(root)
    |> process_queue(acc, reducer)
  end

  def process_queue(queue, acc, reducer) do
    case queue_out(queue) do
      {{:value, {:node, val, left, right}}, popped} ->
        # Process the head of the queue which is the next item in the traversal
        new_acc = reducer.(val, acc)

        # Push in the left then right so that they are processed in that order
        # and so that they are processsed behind earlier nodes that have been
        # found
        popped
        |> queue_in(left)
        |> queue_in(right)
        |> process_queue(new_acc, reducer)

      _other ->
        # Your queue is empty. Return the reduction
        acc
    end
  end

  # These are convenience methods. If the value being pushed in is nil then
  # ignore it so that it is not processed
  def queue_in(queue, nil) do
    queue
  end

  def queue_in(queue, val) do
    :queue.in(val, queue)
  end

  def queue_out(queue) do
    :queue.out(queue)
  end
end
```

The great thing about this approach is that it has tail end recursion.

I hope this helps. Here's a great article on BFS:

https://medium.com/basecs/breaking-down-breadth-first-search-cebe696709d9